# parseFloat in JS for German notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

at the moment I'm trying to implement a Vue.js component that is based on this example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/bgzhw68m/ .

This is how my source looks like:

```
computed: {
            displayValue: {
                get: function get() {
                    if (this.isInputActive) {
                        return this.price.toString();
                    } else {
                        return "€ " + this.price.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\.\d+)?$)/g, "$1,");
                    }
                },
                set: function set(modifiedValue) {
                    var newValue = parseFloat(modifiedValue.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ""));

                    if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                        newValue = 0;
                    }

                    this.price = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
```

This works fine for values like `1.00`, `1,300,500.25` etc.

Now I'd like to use the German way of writing these floats:

In Germany we are writing `1.000.000,50` for `one million and 50 cent`. So you see: `,` and `.` are replaced.

So how can I change my script to get it working with this notation? It's really important, that I'm still able to work with the `float`.

Comment: If you want a robust solution to parse numbers in different locales consider using [numeral](http://numeraljs.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace decimal separator with `,` and then use currency format separator.

For ex:

```js
var price = 332245567
var priceStr=price.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",").replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?:\,\d+)?$)/g, "$1.");
console.log(priceStr)
```

I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/bgzhw68m/422/).

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. Unfortunately the input of `10,20` (which is `10.20`) is not shown correctly. It turns to `1020`.